# How can I access OAuth's state parameter using Passport.js?

Tags: authentication, passport.js

I'm using Passport.js to do authentication, and per [Google's OAuth2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#formingtheurl), I'm passing in a state variable:

```
app.get('/authenticate/googleOAuth', function(request, response) {
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope:
    [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ],
    state: { blah: 'test' }
  })(request, response);
});
```

However, I can't seem to access that variable at a later date:

```
passport.use(new googleStrategy(
{
    clientID: '...',
    clientSecret: '...',
    callbackURL: '...',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  console.log('state: ' + request.query.state);
  login(profile, done);
}));
```

request.query.state is undefined. request.param("state") doesn't work, either.

How can I get at that variable after the authentication callback?

Answer (score 25):

The reason this doesn't work is because you're passing state as an object instead of a string. Seems like passport doesn't stringify that value for you. If you want to pass an object through the state param, you could do something like this:

```
passport.authenticate("google", {
  scope: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
  ],
  state: base64url(JSON.stringify(blah: 'test'))
})(request, response);
```

As Rob DiMarco noted in his answer, you can access the `state` param in the callback `req.query` object.

I'm not sure encoding application state and passing it in the `state` param is a great idea though. The OAuth 2.0 RFC [Section 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) defines state as "an opaque value". It's intended to be used for [CSRF protection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12). A better way to preserve application state in between the authorization request and the callback might be to:

1. generate some `state` parameter value (hash of cookie, for example)
2. persist the application state with `state` as an identifier before initiating the authorization request
3. retrieve the application state in the callback request handler using the `state` param passed back from Google

Comment: Missing { }

state: base64url(JSON.stringify({blah: 'text'}))

Answer (score 1):

Testing this briefly, using Node.js v0.8.9, the runtime-configured parameters for the Google OAuth 2.0 authorization request are eventually formatted via the `getAuthorizeUrl` method in the `node-auth` library. This method relies upon `querystring.stringify` to format the redirect URL:

```
exports.OAuth2.prototype.getAuthorizeUrl= function( params ) {
  var params= params || {};
  params['client_id'] = this._clientId;
  params['type'] = 'web_server';
  return this._baseSite + this._authorizeUrl + "?" + querystring.stringify(params);
}
```

(Above copied from https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/blob/efbce5bd682424a3cb22fd89ab9d82c6e8d68caa/lib/oauth2.js#L123).

Testing in the console using the state parameter you specified:

`querystring.stringify({ state: { blah: 'test' }})` => `'state='`

As a workaround, you can try JSON-encoding your object, or use a single string, which should resolve your issue. You can then access the `state`, in your callback request handler, via `req.query.state`. Remember to `JSON.parse(req.query.state)` when accessing it.

Comment: why `scope` ? I think it's `querystring.stringify({ state: { blah: 'test' }})`, right ?